# Dio package header authorization token details print flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dio

i want to print details of a user and I have user bearer token I tried but it throws a 302 error

```
Future fetchUsers() async {
  Dio dio = Dio();
  dio.options.headers["Authorization"] =
      "Bearer 52|Umoe5JKgwYKoLacx8m2NtO3TJZa36iIqTh7KW3QR";
  dio.options.followRedirects = false;
  Response response = await dio.post("http://52.90.175.175/api/user/get");

  print(response);
```

This is my json
[image]

Comment: shouldn't you be using dio.get()?

Comment: can i use that?

Comment: I assume you're just fetching data and not changing anything. So instead of dio.post(), try using dio.get()

Comment: [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [302]  it throws this error when i use get method